# Use SimpleCursorAdapter for MultiAutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, multiautocompletetextview

I have a database and I would like to use it as data source for `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`. Is it possible utilize `SimpleCursorAdapter` in `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`?

this is code

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN, null, null, null, null, null);
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor,new String[]{"name"},new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0);
    multiText.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: You should show the code that's giving you the trouble.

Comment: in MultiAutoCompleteTextView i use how adapter arrayadapter, now however i would like utilize simplecursoradapter how adapter.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Or are you asking how to use CursorAdapter in general?

Comment: @eispeed - please delete the comment with the code. As you can see, its fairly useless. Instead of adding it as a comment, click *Edit* and add it to your question.